# How to fetch database time and timezone in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I have used the below code for fetching the database time in Acumatica. First thing I have created a stored procedure in the database and I am calling it through code as following.

This works fine in SQL Server, but it doesn't works for MySQL.

Stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetDBtime;

CREATE PROCEDURE GetDBtime()
BEGIN
    SELECT SYSDATE();
END
```

C# code:

```
protected void UserPreferences_UsrKNDBTime_FieldSelecting(PXCache cache, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
{
       var row = (UserPreferences)e.Row;

       if (row != null)
       {
           foreach (var results in PXDatabase.Execute("GetDBtime", new PXSPParameter[] { new PXSPOutParameter("dateTimere", PXDbType.DateTime, null) }))
           {
               DateTime? dbTime = (DateTime)results;

               if (dbTime != null)
               {
                   e.ReturnValue = dbTime;
               }
               break;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to implement this yourself - there's already a function in the Acumatica framework that will give you the server date time. Simply call `PXTransactionScope.GetServerDateTime`.